# Convert String To Date Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

how can i convert the following string to the required format in javascript:

```
2013-12-01 03:22:03 = 01 Dec '13
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try just passing that string to new Date()

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be solved by simply passing the string to new Date()

Comment: Are you asking how to get the Date(2013-12-01 03:22:03) to print as "01 Dec '13"?

Comment: Certainly looks like it. Not all browser will accept the dashes in the date by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LefJK/)

```
function conv(str) {
  var d=new Date(str.replace(/-/g,"/"));
  var day = d.getDate();
  if (day<10) day ="0"+day;
  var yyyy=""+d.getFullYear();
  return ""+day +" "+["Jan","Feb",..."Dec"][d.getMonth()]+" '"+yyyy.substring(2);
}

var dStr = conv("2013-12-01 03:22:03");
```

The reason to convert from - to / is that not all browsers accept the format with -

Answer (score 1):

```
new Date('2013-12-01 03:22:03');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date